# Русские названия файлов и модуль playsound

Tags: python

В python я относительно новичок. У меня возникла надобность открыть файл, но там название некоторых файлов идёт на русском языке и идёт что-то вроде

```
playsound('C:/Users/User/Documents/Audacity/Секретный звук.wav')
```

и вот тут мне выдаёт ошибку

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Неизвестный.py", line 9, in <module>
playsound('C:/Users/User/Documents/Audacity/Секретный звук.wav')
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

я знаю, что можно впихнуть это аудио в одну папку с кодом и переименовать а ля английские язык и цифры, но всё же как использовать в путях к файлу и названия самого файла в python на русском языке? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы не привели пример своего кода, в котором возникает ошибка.

Comment: @DiHASTRO, откатил вопрос до более ранней версии. Не нужно "мусорить" в вопросе. Вопрос не только для вас, но и для других людей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: На 15 июля 2021 года проблема уже должна быть исправлена, судя по [комментарию автора модуля](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/29#issuecomment-880306789)

---

Это баг библиотеки playsound. [Смотрим код](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/master/playsound.py#L21):

```
def winCommand(*command):
    buf = c_buffer(255)
    command = ' '.join(command).encode(getfilesystemencoding())  # <--
    errorCode = int(windll.winmm.mciSendStringA(command, buf, 254, 0))  # <--
    if errorCode:
        errorBuffer = c_buffer(255)
        windll.winmm.mciGetErrorStringA(errorCode, errorBuffer, 254)  # <--
        exceptionMessage = ('\n    Error ' + str(errorCode) + ' for command:'
                            '\n        ' + command.decode() +  # <--
                            '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())  # <--
        raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
    return buf.value
```

Первая проблема - берется `getfilesystemencoding()` (под Windows 10, например, это utf-8), потом этой кодировкой кодируется команда (часть которой - ваш путь к файлу с русскими буквами). Получаем набор байт в кодировке utf-8. И дальше передаем этот набор байт в функцию, `mciGetErrorStringA`, буква `A` в имени которой говорит нам, что функция поддерживает только однобайтовые кодировки (в отличие от функций с буквой `W` в конце - они поддерживают utf-16). Функция не срабатывает, возвращает код ошибки.

Потом срабатывает `if`, пытаемся получить текст ошибки (опять же, с помощью ANSI версии функции `mciGetErrorString`). Дальше команда, изначально закодированная в utf-8, декодируется кодировкой по-умолчанию (в этот раз повезло - это оказалась тоже utf-8).

Дальше берется буфер с текстом ошибки, также декодируется из кодировкой по-умолчанию (в вашем случае это скорее всего utf-8), но т.к. содержимое этого буфера заполнила функция, рассчитанная на однобайтовые кодировки, то в буфере, внезапно, оказывается текст на русском в кодировке cp1251. Получаем ошибку из вопроса.

Фиксим на коленке:

```
def winCommand(*command):
    buf = c_buffer(512)
    command = ' '.join(command).encode('utf-16')
    errorCode = int(windll.winmm.mciSendStringW(command, buf, 511, 0))
    if errorCode:
        errorBuffer = c_buffer(512)
        windll.winmm.mciGetErrorStringW(errorCode, errorBuffer, 511)
        exceptionMessage = ('\n    Error ' + str(errorCode) + ' for command:'
                            '\n        ' + command.decode('utf-16') +
                            '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode('utf-16'))
        raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
    return buf.value
```

В приниципе, можно добавить пулл-реквест к библиотеке.

## Обновлено

Протестировал у себя, внес еще несколько исправлений, полный код функции `_playsoundWin`:

```
def _playsoundWin(sound, block = True):
    '''
    Utilizes windll.winmm. Tested and known to work with MP3 and WAVE on
    Windows 7 with Python 2.7. Probably works with more file formats.
    Probably works on Windows XP thru Windows 10. Probably works with all
    versions of Python.

    Inspired by (but not copied from) Michael Gundlach <gundlach@gmail.com>'s mp3play:
    https://github.com/michaelgundlach/mp3play

    I never would have tried using windll.winmm without seeing his code.
    '''
    import string
    from ctypes import c_buffer, windll
    from random import random
    from time   import sleep
    from sys    import getfilesystemencoding

    def winCommand(*command):
        buf = c_buffer(512)
        command = ' '.join(command)
        errorCode = int(windll.winmm.mciSendStringW(command.encode('utf-16'), buf, 511, 0))
        if errorCode:
            errorBuffer = c_buffer(512)
            windll.winmm.mciGetErrorStringW(errorCode, errorBuffer, 511)
            exceptionMessage = ('\n    Error ' + str(errorCode) + ' for command:'
                                '\n        ' + command +
                                '\n    ' + errorBuffer.raw.decode('utf-16').rstrip('\0'))
            
            raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
        return buf.raw.decode('utf-16').rstrip('\0')

    alias = ('playsound_' + str(random()))[:28]  # Avoid aliases longer then 28
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
    winCommand('set', alias, 'time format milliseconds')
    durationInMS = winCommand('status', alias, 'length')
    winCommand('play', alias, 'from 0 to', durationInMS)

    if block:
        sleep(float(durationInMS) / 1000.0)
```

## Обновление 2

- Пулл-реквест: https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/pull/32
- Мой форк пакета с исправлением: https://github.com/insolor/playsound
  Можно обновить пакет прямо с github (потребуется установленный [git](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/29#issuecomment-880306789)):

  ```
    pip install -U git+https://github.com/insolor/playsound
  ```

## Обновление 3

Судя по [комментарию автора модуля](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/29#issuecomment-880306789), он выпустил свой вариант исправления. Я его не тестировал, но предполагаю, что исправление рабочее, поэтому свой форк удалил. Пулл реквест я также закрыл, но изменения в нем можно посмотреть при желании.

Comment: А как изменить собственно эту библиотеку? Или это просто впихнуть в код? Мой прожжённый самовар не может переварить как это и куда. Вашу ссылку на гитхаб посмотрел, но там выходит у меня в библиотеке, что заканчивается всё дело на

 I never would have tried using windll.winmm without seeing his code

и всё

Comment: В тексте ошибки указан путь к файлу `playsound.py`: `File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py"`, в нем эту функцию нужно изменить

Comment: Ссылка в ответе указывает на начало функции в файле (просто указал источник, откуда взят код)

Comment: Дабы не умничать решил сделать через гит и теперь мне выходит такая вот ошибка:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ussr.py", line 13, in <module>
    playsound("C:/Users/User/Documents/Audacity/ссср.wav")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 36, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('set', alias, 'time format milliseconds')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)`

Comment: `playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 290 for command:
        set playsound_0.020130626161719234 time format milliseconds
    Указан недопустимый параметр для данной команды.`

Comment: Посмотрю. Не исключено что ошибка из-за слишком длинного алиаса.

Comment: Похоже что действительно проблема в длинных алиасах (длиннее 28, в вашем случае это было 30 символов). Обновил код в ответе и на гитхабе.

Comment: Привет. Слушай, у меня такая ошибка возникает: `Error 263 for command:
        set playsound_0.2599447444735145 time format milliseconds
    Указанное устройство не открыто или не опознается интерфейсом MCI`. В чем может быть проблема, не подскажешь?

Comment: @МихаилМуратов без понятия

Comment: А предположения есть хотя бы?

Comment: @МихаилМуратов нет

Comment: Очень грустно. Мне нужно использовать в игре библиотеку для воспроизведения звуков, и чтобы эта библиотека мало весила. Решил посмотреть в сторону `playsound`, но что-то не повезло((((((((

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в виндовозе, но (IMHO) проблема в том, что питоновские программы (начиная с версии 3) работают на UTF-8, а имена каталогов на виндовозных дисках пишутся в формате cp1251.

Может быть стоит попробовать нечто вроде:

```
file_name = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Audacity/Секретный звук.wav'
playsound(file_name.encode(encoding="cp1251")
```

Comment: «имена каталогов на виндовозных дисках пишутся в формате cp1251» — ну нет же, в NTFS отродясь используется кодировка UTF-16